# Algorithm for shuffling recycled data

Tags: algorithm, random

I have a program which asks the user a question. If the user doesn't know the answer, he can skip it.

But if he answers wrong, that question is allotted negative points and then that question must be asked again randomly any time during the quiz.

If the question is answered correctly, the question need not be asked again.

Is there any algorithm to shuffle the questions like that?

Comment: Yes there is an algorithm. Do you want us to write the answer for your homework?

Comment: Yes, there should be an algorithm for this, now all you have to do is find out and then try. Later when you face issue, come back here. :)

Comment: This is a good question. The asker has a specific problem that he wants to solve and he's looking for an algorithm to do it. See this Meta question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271842/is-it-okay-to-just-ask-for-an-algorithm-to-a-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to store the questions in a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). Initially the `n` questions are assigned priorities 1 through `n`. Subsequently, when you want to recycle a question, you assign it a new priority chosen at random from `x` through `n + 1`, where `x` is the number of questions that have been removed from the priority queue. Now you reinsert the question and proceed as usual.

If you implement the priority queue with a heap, you'll face a dilemma in dealing with elements of equal priority. Ordinarily you would stop bubbling an element through the heap as soon as the element keys are equal. In your case, this would have an adverse effect on the quiz because equal-priority elements would not be sorted uniformly at random—their position in the heap would depend on the order of insertion.

You can get around this problem by using floating-point values with double precision. Now the initial priorities are 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, and so on. Subsequently, you choose a random floating-point value from the range `[1.0 * x, n + 1.0]`, where, again, `x` is the number of questions removed from the priority queue and `n` is the number of questions you began with. Now you don't have a problem with equal keys because there is practically zero chance that you'll randomly choose one of the existing double-precision values. The chance is not actually zero, but it's less than the odds that a meteor will strike your computer today.